How can I add my applications in the "Open With..." menu of digiKam?
I have applications like DxO PureRaw4, Luminar Neo, Affinity Photo, etc. How can I open an image I see in digiKam in one of those applications?
I'm using digiKam Version 8.4.0 on Windows 10 64bit.

Browse to %ProgramFiles%\digiKam\data\applications and create a new .desktop file for each application. There should already be a couple examples, and I used an existing one as template.
For example, for DxO PureRaw4, I created a file dxo_pr4.desktop with this content:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=DxO PureRaw4
Name[en_GB]=DxO PureRaw4
X-Exec="%ProgramFiles%/DxO/DxO PureRAW 4/PureRawv4.exe" %f
X-Icon="%ProgramFiles%/DxO/DxO PureRAW 4/PureRawv4.exe"
MimeType=image/jpg;image/raw


Likewise for luminar with luminar_neo.desktop (here I didn't remove the localization entries):
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Luminar Neo
Name[be]=Luminar Neo
Name[bg]=Luminar Neo
Name[ca]=Luminar Neo
Name[ca@valencia]=Luminar Neo
Name[cs]=Luminar Neo
Name[en_GB]=Luminar Neo
Name[eo]=Luminar Neo
Name[es]=Luminar Neo
Name[eu]=Luminar Neo
Name[fr]=Luminar Neo
Name[is]=Luminar Neo
Name[it]=Luminar Neo
Name[ka]=Luminar Neo
Name[nl]=Luminar Neo
Name[sl]=Luminar Neo
Name[sv]=Luminar Neo
Name[tr]=Luminar Neo
Name[uk]=Luminar Neo
Name[x-test]=xxLuminar Neoxx
Name[zh_CN]=Luminar Neo
Name[zh_TW]=Luminar Neo
X-Exec="%ProgramFiles%/Skylum/Luminar Neo/Luminar Neo.exe" %f
X-Icon="%ProgramFiles%/Skylum/Luminar Neo/Luminar Neo.exe"
MimeType=image/jpg;image/raw


The 2 applications became immediately available in the context menu:

